# c# Computing Hashes - Persisting state between multiple streams

Tags: c#, .net, hash, sha1

I'm currently implementing chunked file uploads. Ideally I want to compute a SHA1 hash of the uploaded file. However, I am streaming the file directly to the database which is in a remote location so is a performance hit each time it is accessed.

I am using the following code to compute the hash of a single bulk upload as used in our offline application:

```
...
...
using (var uploadStream = SqlDataUploadStream.Create(initial, subsequent))
using (var sha1Hasher = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create())
using (var hashStream = new CryptoStream(uploadStream, sha1Hasher, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
{
    ...
    Copy to hashStream here...
    ...
}
```

Of course since the uploads via HTTP are being chunked, there isn't a single continuous stream I can compute the hash against.

However, if I can somehow get and set the internal state of the hashing class itself I could persist the state between chunk posts and compute the hash like that without having to go back to the database at the end to read the whole thing again. Unfortunately a quick look at MSDN page for the SHA1 class, nothing jumped out at me that I could use to get the internal state.

I could persist the whole hash class in session, but as it wants to be disposed I am a bit weary of doing this just in case something goes wrong and I don't get a chance to manually dispose it.

So, is there any way I can grab the internal state?

Comment: The session will eventually be cleaned up by the system and any resources held in the has object will eventually be cleaned up by the GC. I would recommend storing it in the session.

Comment: You could use an alternative implementation that allows access to the internal state.

Comment: I'd have a look at [Merkel tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree), looks like good use-case for it.

Comment: What database?  Can you compute the hash on the database end?

Comment: Can't you just write each chunk once to the hash stream and once to the upload component that you are using?; If you want to persist the hash state, either use SHA1Managed (no need to dispose) or just use some other library.

Comment: I'm using MSSQL and its hashing function only takes max 8k as an input. The use of SHA1Maanaged is a good call, I'll take a look at that. @usr If you put that as an answer I'll mark it correct once I've got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to persist the hash state, either use `SHA1Managed` (no need to dispose) or just use some other library. Although `SHA1Managed` is `IDisposable` nothing in its implementation makes use of that fact.

You mentioned putting it into the session. That's a dirty thing because now the user can only have one concurrent upload. A typical case of session misuse, I'd say. I'd rather store the hashing state in the database next to the blob that you are in the process of creating.

Comment: I'm using a dictionary which takes the file ID as key, to store upload state. I'm using PLUpload which generates this ID, and its very unlikely to clash within the same session.

Comment: I had to ditch using the CryptoStream as when that is disposed it calls TransformFinalBlock on the underlying hash class - but oh well not the end of the world having to read the posted chunks in two passes.

Comment: You should be able to call the underlying transform directly. It has an interface that is very similar to a stream.